# Angular2: Sum two Observable<number> values

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a service with two different functions that get the number of itens inside an array that is watched by an BehaviorSubject.

```
 private itemsInCartSubject: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
private itemsInCart: any[] = [];

private packetsInCartSubject: BehaviorSubject<Pacote[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
private packetsInCart: Pacote[] = [];

 public getTotalItens(): Observable<number> {        

    return this.itemsInCartSubject.map((items: any[]) => {
        return items.reduce((prev, curr: any) => {               
                return prev + Number(curr.qtd);                
        }, 0);
    });
};

   public getTotalPacotes(): Observable<number> {
    return this.packetsInCartSubject.map((items: any[]) => {
        return items.reduce((prev, curr: any) => {               
                return prev + Number(1);                
        }, 0);
    });
};
```

Inside my component I have two methods to get these numbers:

```
 public countItens(): Observable<number> {
    return this.cartService.getTotalItens();
}

public countPacotes(): Observable<number> {
    return this.cartService.getTotalPacotes();
}
```

In my html I can show the values like this:

```
<p>You have {{countItens() | async}} in your cart</p>
```

It works fine, updating the values when theres is a change on the subject, but I need to sum the two values of the two Observables.

How can I accomplish that?

I've tried

```
this.cartService.getTotalItens()+this.cartService.getTotalPacotes();
```

But it generates the error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types Observable and Observable

Comment: http://rxmarbles.com/ and http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html are best resources I've found when trying to figure out this kind of stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine these Observables using `combineLatest` and then return a new value that is the sum of both. You can add a new function like this:

```js
public getTotal(): Observable<number> {
    return this.countItens()
               .combineLatest(this.countPacotes(), (itens, pacotes) => itens + pacotes);
}
```

And then in the template you can use it like so:

```html
<p>Total is: {{getTotal() | async}}</p>
```

[Demo of combineLatest](https://jsfiddle.net/pumpdude93/b60bx0qq/1/)

Comment: Map has one argument which is array where 0 element  will be the first value etc haven't it?

Comment: One more thing, you don't need the map. The last argument of combinelatest is function that will may sum all the things, it has two arguments as yours map :)

Comment: It's worth to mention that when we call a `function` in template, it's called on every change detection, no matter what... dependending on how many interactions you do in this specific page, performance can be affected. Consider assign the result of this `function` to a variable.